# I asked a question that is similar to a few other questions: now what?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

I asked a question that is not identical to any other questions, but is similar to several. In fact, I think I could answer most of my question by reviewing the other questions. I searched before making my original post but for whatever reason didn't find the other threads.

So which of the following is better:

- review the other questions and then edit my OP to differentiate focusing on any areas I still don't understand or do not totally overlap?
- answer my own question referencing the other questions but leaving the original post intact?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, deal with the question "is my question an exact duplicate of another post?" If it is, flag your own post for closure.

However you said that questions you have found are similar, but different enough. Edit into your question that you have found these post, and address how they don't fit your needs. This shows research effort, and helps deter dup close votes.

Now, if the other posts you have found *in combination* solve your original problem, self-answer your question. Give credit to all the sources you found, and explain in detail. It's your job to say "these are the pieces of the puzzle I found, and this is how I put them together."